Error using Simple Java Mail on a JavaFX project
I have this code on a test project and it works fine, but I don't know why when I put it on my package on the JavaFX project I want to use it for real this line:
.from("example", "example@outlook.com")


Uncompilable code - cannot access jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress   class file for jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress not found

This is my module-info class
module com.mycompany.proyectodam {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.base;
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires org.simplejavamail;

    opens com.mycompany.proyectodam to javafx.fxml;
    opens com.mycompany.bd to javafx.base;
    exports com.mycompany.proyectodam;
}

and this is the code
import org.simplejavamail.api.email.Email;
import org.simplejavamail.api.mailer.Mailer;
import org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Email email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
                                  .from("example", "example@outlook.com")
                                  .to("example", "example@icloud.com")
                                  .withSubject("test subject")
                                  .withPlainText("test")
                                  .buildEmail();

        Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder.withSMTPServer("smtp.office365.com", 587, "example@outlook.com", "dasdasdasdasdasda")
                                     .buildMailer();
        mailer.sendMail(email);
        System.out.println("Correo enviado con éxito!");
    }
}


The simplejavamail code as of the latest version (8.10.1) is not modular (in terms of the Java platform module system).
The documentation talks a lot about modules. However, these are not well-defined Java modules with module-info.java for each module. Instead, many modules are automatic modules.
If you have automatic modules in your code base, I advise refactoring to make your project non-modular. Automatic modules do not receive the full benefits of modularization (e.g. complete modular encapsulation with well-defined transitive required modules and jlinked runtimes).
To develop a non-modular project (delete your module-info.java) that relies on a modular JavaFX implementation, either:

Use a JDK/JRE that includes JavaFX (such as Azul or Liberica "JDK FX" or "Full JDK" versions)

OR

Follow the openjfx.io instructions for non-modular projects. Placing required JavaFX modules on the module path using command line switches.

